# using a php request with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP script which returns a table of high-scores in HTML. How would I then render this in WordPress? A friend suggested using an iframe but that seems to be for images to me. Does anyone have any suggestions; I can't figure it out

the code that is created on the script is

```
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$rows['name'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['score'] . "</td>";
echo '</tr>';
// close while loop 
}
```

with a `<table> </table>` tag at each end respectively

Comment: iFrames are for any type of content, not just images.

Comment: An iFrame is also likely the easiest route for you to take unless you want to dabble with some more complex PHP/JS stuff or messing around with plugins.

Comment: How would i go about it then? just put a link to my php script as the iframe src?

Comment: Yep! iFrames are straight forward. You can even include pages from external websites.

Comment: Is the data for the high scores in the same database as the WordPress install?

Comment: nah its from a seperate webserver im hosting

Comment: Don't use an iframe, they cause as many issues as they solve. Create a `shortcode` in WordPress that calls the remote site using cURL or write a small AJAX call that will do the same thing.

Comment: @BA_Webimax how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and easy jQuery solution you can throw this in a page:

```
<div id="highScores"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#highScores").html('<object data="http://example.com/highscores.php">');
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried using that but every time i switch from html to visual it pretty much removes all the code and returns a white screen

Comment: and previewing just shows 'jQuery(“#highScores”).html(”)'

Comment: There is nothing to display, so the visual editor would not show anything. Try saving while still in the text editor.

Comment: You could also try throwing it in a template file.

Answer (score -1):

You could set this up as a [page template in your theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/).

Comment: Hi Daniel, I recommend copy-pasting the relevant info from your link into your answer. This means that future readers will still be able to access the information even if the website changes or goes down.